# How to get the most recent message of a channel in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to get the most recent message of a specific channel using discord.py? I looked at the official docs and didn't find a way to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've now figured it out by myself:

For a `discord.Client` class you just need these lines of code for the last message:

```py
(await self.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID).history(limit=1).flatten())[0]
```

If you use a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` @thegamecracks' answer is correct.

Comment: NameError: name 'self' is not defined   . You know how to fix?

Comment: @ThomasKerby You need to extend a discord.Client class in order to use this.

Answer (score 8):

(Answer uses `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instead of `discord.Client`; I haven't worked with the lower level parts of the API, so this may not apply to `discord.Client`)

In this case, you can use [`Bot.get_channel(ID)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_channel) to acquire the channel you want to inspect.

```
channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(ID))
```

Then, you can use [`channel.last_message_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.last_message_id) to get the ID of the last message, and acquire the message with [`channel.fetch_message(ID)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message).

```
message = await channel.fetch_message(
    channel.last_message_id)
```

Combined, a command to get the last message of a channel may look like this:

```
@commands.command(
    name='getlastmessage')
async def client_getlastmessage(self, ctx, ID):
    """Get the last message of a text channel."""
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(ID))
    if channel is None:
        await ctx.send('Could not find that channel.')
        return
    # NOTE: get_channel can return a TextChannel, VoiceChannel,
    # or CategoryChannel. You may want to add a check to make sure
    # the ID is for text channels only

    message = await channel.fetch_message(
        channel.last_message_id)
    # NOTE: channel.last_message_id could return None; needs a check

    await ctx.send(
        f'Last message in {channel.name} sent by {message.author.name}:\n'
        + message.content
    )
    # NOTE: message may need to be trimmed to fit within 2000 chars
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way
for the newer versions

```
messages = [message async for message in interaction.guild.get_channel(0).history(limit=12)]
messages[0].content
```

Comment: limit should be 1, but thanks! I've been looking for this.

Comment: just turn limit to 1 and you will be all good