# How to repeat the most recent message in a discord server - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

it's been a while since I've done any python at all, so please forgive me if the answer is obvious or if this is an easy fix. I started creating a discord bot for a server I'm in, and I was asked to create an echo command. They want the text repeated, and then the command usage to be deleted. I know some discord.py but I have struggled with copying (and probably will have trouble with sending) the most recent message, which I think will be the easiest way to do this. My code so far:

```
if message.content.startswith("mo.echo"):
msg = await self.get_channel(801451745875066950).history(limit=1).flatten()
msg = msg[0]
await message.delete()
```

The error is:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Can someone please assist me in fixing this error. The code came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080277/how-to-get-the-most-recent-message-of-a-channel-in-discord-py) and the question is nearly a year old which is why I'm not surprised that this may not work. I'm using a `client.event`. If you have a better method of doing this then please tell. If there is a working answer out there please point me into that direction and I can take action on my own post (deleting or answering or marking it with and answer elsewhere).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use self instead of client.
This should work:

```
#change self to client
if message.content.startswith("mo.echo"):
    msg = await client.get_channel(801451745875066950).history(limit=1).flatten()
    msg = msg[0]
    await message.delete()
```

Comment: Ok thx lol, such a simple solution! Please can you tell me, if you know, how do i then send the text (preferably without the command) into the channel. It sends a really long message instead of what was intended. `[<Message id=884044101677367376 channel=<TextChannel id=801451745875066950 name='moon-server-bot' position=2 nsfw=False news=False category_id=799988044169216030> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=530791679704301580 name='daTXOGllama' discriminator='1234' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>]`

Comment: @TXOG that's the string representation of a `Message` instance. You're not supposed to send a `Message`, you're supposed to send the **content** of the message.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```py
if message.content.startswith("mo.echo"):
  await message.channel.send(message.content.replace("mo.echo ", ""))
  await message.delete()
```

it will send the message they sent, but without the command part